# Improving Rails feed parser

Tags: optimization, ruby, ruby-on-rails, parsing

This is my feed parser method using feedzirra. It works, but I feel dirty because I can't figure out how to improve this code. Any suggestions?

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :summary, :url, :published_at, :guid

  def self.update_from_feed
    feed_urls = ["url1", "url2", "ulr3", "url4"]
    feeds = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_urls)

    feeds.each do |url|
      feeds = url.last.entries
      feeds.each do |entry|
        logger.debug "Questo e l'oggetto #{entry}"
        unless exists? :guid => entry.entry_id
          create!(
            :name         => entry.title,
            :summary      => entry.summary,
            :url          => entry.url,
            :published_at => entry.published,
            :guid         => entry.entry_id
          )
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

This is the object returned from the fetch_and_parse method: **with just the first URL**

```
{"http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/rss2"=>#<Feedzirra::Parser::RSS:0x00000005db8e68 @title="rss", @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina", @entries=[#<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005db6500 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207121646-cro-rt10178-prestiti_denominati_in_yuan_in_crescita", @entry_id="dY_9w7JofPUA7twYye5aMg", @title=" PRESTITI DENOMINATI IN YUAN IN CRESCITA", @summary="Pechino, 12 lug. ? Impennata per i nuovi prestiti denominati in\nyuan nel mese di giugno, grazie all'iniziativa del governo per\nstimolare l'economia in rallentamento.", @published=2012-07-12 14:45:17 UTC>, #<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005dc8fe8 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207121645-cro-rt10177-pechino_stretta_su_spese_funzionari_pubblici", @entry_id="3PxPS6grfUl2G2d0NyLahA", @title=" PECHINO, STRETTA SU SPESE FUNZIONARI PUBBLICI", @summary="Pechino, 12 lug. ? Il governo municipale di Pechino rafforzerà\ni controlli sui viaggi all'estero dei funzionari per\npartecipare ad attività di formazione.", @published=2012-07-12 14:44:42 UTC>, #<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005dc6ce8 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207091655-cro-rt10173-colata_di_fango_nel_sichuan_14_morti_confermati", @entry_id="h74sGs2DolJKaZZyZWl84g", @title=" COLATA DI FANGO NEL SICHUAN, 14 MORTI CONFERMATI", @summary="Chengdu, 9 lug.- I soccorritori hanno recuperato i corpi di 14\npersone dopo che una colata di fango, provocata dalle piogge,\naveva colpito la provincia del Sichuan lo scorso 28 giugno.", @published=2012-07-09 14:55:11 UTC>, #<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005ebb1f8 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207091655-cro-rt10171-attivisti_giapponesi_sulle_diaoyu_proteste_cinesi", @entry_id="7bh55Qqb5dcEijmhCbtLYA", @title=" ATTIVISTI GIAPPONESI SULLE DIAOYU, PROTESTE CINESI", @summary="Pechino, 9 lug.- La Cina ha presentato solenni rimostranze e\nproteste verso il Giappone per aver violato la sua sovranita'\nterritoriale, dopo che due attivisti giapponesi sono sbarcati\nsulle isole Diaoyu.", @published=2012-07-09 14:54:29 UTC>, #<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005ec0ef0 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207091654-cro-rt10170-incontro_tra_funzionari_di_cina_e_asean", @entry_id="fIrGROI7wDYX0pxsoiS9og", @title=" INCONTRO TRA FUNZIONARI DI CINA E ASEAN", @summary="Phnom Penh, 9 lug.- Domenica si sono incontrati alti funzionari\nin rappresentanza di Cina e Asean, in vista della prossima\nriunione dei ministri degli Esteri.", @published=2012-07-09 14:54:07 UTC>, #<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005ebebf0 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207061449-cro-rt10139-eclac_si_a_piu_cooperazione_cina_america_latina", @entry_id="K7sni4Vq4wnUEQvtxjKbmg", @title=" ECLAC, SI' A PIU' COOPERAZIONE CINA-AMERICA LATINA", @summary="Santiago, 6 lug. - Elogio alle recenti proposte di Wen Jiabao\nper rafforzare le relazioni di cooperazione tra Cina e America\nLatina.", @published=2012-07-06 12:48:26 UTC>, #<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005ec7048 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207061448-cro-rt10138-maxi_retata_contro_traffico_di_bambini", @entry_id="aeJgnkQBbTr6finnow2Ckw", @title=" MAXI RETATA CONTRO TRAFFICO DI BAMBINI", @summary="Pechino, 6 lug. - La polizia cinese ha sgominato lunedi' due\ngrandi bande di traffico di bambini: 802 i sospettati\narrestati, 181 i bambini liberati.", @published=2012-07-06 12:47:57 UTC>, #<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005ec4d48 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207061448-cro-rt10137-hong_kong_record_di_investimenti_esteri", @entry_id="UNxnzwr3oPFEOtES1W4YPg", @title=" HONG KONG, RECORD DI INVESTIMENTI ESTERI", @summary="Hong Kong, 6 lug. - Nel 2011 gli investimenti diretti esteri\n(Fdi) a Hong Kong hanno superato gli 83 miliardi di dollari\nstatunitensi, un record storico, per un piu' 17% rispetto al\n2010.", @published=2012-07-06 12:47:17 UTC>, #<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005ecda60 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207051516-cro-rt10164-xinjiang_esercitazioni_antiterrorismo", @entry_id="lxvg0rXeNbKGaHiiueQ2tA", @title=" XINJIANG, ESERCITAZIONI ANTITERRORISMO", @summary="Urumqi, 5 lug. - Effettuata un'esercitazione antiterrorismo da\nparte di forze speciali a Urumqi, nella regione autonoma del\nXinjiang Uygur.", @published=2012-07-05 13:15:29 UTC>, #<Feedzirra::Parser::RSSEntry:0x00000005ecb760 @url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/notizie/201207051515-cro-rt10163-raul_castro_a_pechino_per_visita_di_stato", @entry_id="kJjP4UZ_rmbMTyIBKpNRcA", @title=" RAUL CASTRO A PECHINO PER VISITA DI STATO", @summary="Pechino, 5 lug. -  Raul Castro Ruz e' giunto mercoledi' a\nPechino per una visita di Stato in Cina, su invito del\npresidente Hu Jintao.", @published=2012-07-05 13:14:25 UTC>], @feed_url="http://www.agichina24.it/home/agenzia-nuova-cina/rss2", @etag=nil, @last_modified=nil>}
```

I've tried everything, but only that solution works.

Answer (score 2):

Slight cleanup:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def self.update_from_feed
    feed_urls = ["url1", "url2", "ulr3", "url4"]
    Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_urls).each do |_, feeds|
      feeds.entries.each do |entry|
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

1. No need to store a local variable called feeds anymore.
2. If you call .each on a hash, you can use |key, value| in the block.

2a. Since url isn't getting used anymore, |url, feeds| becomes |_, feeds|.

Thoughts?

Comment: Oops -- super necro here. Didn't realize how unpopulated codereview.stackexchange was...

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but we're working on that, Kyle :) I stumbled on your answer and I think it looks good. I hope you will stick around here more.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names in your blocks are very confusing, especially where you introduce another `feeds`.  Just go with the least surprising names possible:

```
feed_urls = ["url1", "url2", "ulr3", "url4"]
feeds = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_urls)

feeds.each do |feed|
  entries = feed.last.entries
  entries.each do |entry|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Also, adding parentheses would help make this easier for programmers to parse:

```
exists?(:guid => entry.entry_id)
```